# How to iterate fields of a shape in hacklang?

Tags: hacklang

Say I have a shape like this

```
$something = shape(
  'some_key' => ...,
  'another_key' => ...,
  ...
);
```

How can I iterate each field of the shape? I'm looking for something like this

```
foreach ($something as $key) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Note that while the answer below answers your question, you should consider if a shape is actually the right data structure -- if you need to iterate the structure, a dictionary might be more suitable. (Shapes are great when you have fixed keys and thus pull out specific keys -- if you need to iterate, that often sounds like a dict!)

Comment: @JoshWatzman Thanks for the input, I was attempting to implement my change to pre-existing code which was currently using shapes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert to a `dict` first with the built-in [`HH\Shapes::toDict`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/HH.Shapes/toDict/) then iterate:

```
foreach(HH\Shapes::toDict($something) as $k => $v) {
  // ...
}
```